# Connect IIS to Docker Image Running Shiny Server

Tags: r, docker, iis, shiny, shiny-server

I have a Shiny App that I am trying to host on a Windows Server. From what I've researched, the only way this is possible is to dockerize the Shiny App first. The part where I'm confused/ don't really know what I'm doing is, after I create the docker container for the Shiny App and put it on Shiny Server in the container, how do I point IIS to spin up the container and host it on a url?

Any guidance or if you could point me to some resources for help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need IIS in the big picture? You can expose the Docker container  to handle external traffic without IIS.

Comment: Hi @LexLi, I didn't know that. Do you have any suggestions for things to google, or any articles?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=expose+docker+container+to+internet&oq=expose+docker+conta&aqs=edge.0.0i512l3j69i57j0i512l3.3902j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8